# Jpgraph: Show whole year even if some months are missing

Tags: php, jpgraph

I want to show the values for each month in a graph. But depending on the year, months in the beginning or the end are missing (e.g. because values had only been recorded from April, not January, or because the current year isn't over yet).

Currently, Jpgraph will then only show the months that have values. But I'd like there to still be 12 sections, the missing ones should just be empty/zero.

Is there a way to have Jpgraph show the missing months?

Thanks,
MrB

Answer (score 2):

step by step:

1. go to php.ini
2. find "memory_limit"
3. change value and Put it in the 32MB.(For Example)
4. Enjoy!

good luck